# ListView Grouping WPF - show only groups with multiple items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Let's say I group ObservableCollection by column "time".
How can I display only groups with multiple items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit crude, but you can collapse the groups you don't want:

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemCount}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

It's somewhat frustrating to work with this, because of the poor quality of the WPF documentation. [GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle.headertemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) better than most of WPF, but they still, preposterously, can't be bothered to tell you *what type the DataContext for the template is* or what its properties are. Well, it's [MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle.headertemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If the above doesn't apply to what you're doing, that's what you get for writing vague one-line questions with no detail.

Comment: Could you post an example? I can't find anything that uses grouping and filters based on grouping.